# Load videos on mac OS using MediaLibrary

Tags: swift, macos, media-library

I am trying to load videos on Mac using swift 3 and apple's MLMediaLibrary. I have downloaded the sample code from apple that loads photos from the url: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MediaLibraryLoader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017375

I am trying to change the code to load videos instead of photos. Below is my code sample. I realised that MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey should be MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier only to access videos within Photos App. However, it is not loading videos and gives message "unsupported surface format: 420f" in console.

What can I do to show only videos here ?

```
import Cocoa
import MediaLibrary

class IconViewBox : NSBox {
override func hitTest(_ aPoint: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    // Don't allow any mouse clicks for subviews in this NSBox.
    return nil
  }
}

// MARK: -

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate {

// MARK: - Types

// Keys describing the dictionary for each photo loaded.
private struct ItemKeys {
    static let imageKey = "icon"
    static let nameKey = "name"
}

// MLMediaLibrary property values for KVO.
private struct MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys {
    static let mediaSourcesKey = "mediaSources"
    static let rootMediaGroupKey = "rootMediaGroup"
    static let mediaObjectsKey = "mediaObjects"
    static let contentTypeKey = "contentType"
}

// MARK: - Properties

/**
 The KVO contexts for `MLMediaLibrary`.
 This provides a stable address to use as the `context` parameter for KVO observation methods.
 */
private var mediaSourcesContext = 1
private var rootMediaGroupContext = 2
private var mediaObjectsContext = 3

private var photoSize = CGSize(width: 168, height: 145)

// Contains an array of dictionaries describing each photo (refer to ItemKeys for key/values).
@IBOutlet weak var arrayController: NSArrayController!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
@IBOutlet private weak var noPhotosLabel: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet private weak var activityIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!

// MLMediaLibrary instances for loading the photos.
private var mediaLibrary: MLMediaLibrary!
private var mediaSource: MLMediaSource!
private var rootMediaGroup: MLMediaGroup!

// MARK: - View Controller Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Start progress indicator in case fetching the photos from the photo library takes time.
    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimation(self)

    self.collectionView.minItemSize = self.photoSize
    self.collectionView.maxItemSize = self.photoSize

    self.arrayController.setSelectionIndex(-1)  // No selection to start out with.

    // Setup the media library to load only photos, don't include other source types.
    let options: [String : AnyObject] =
        [MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey: MLMediaSourceType.image.rawValue as AnyObject,
         MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey: [MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier, MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier] as AnyObject]

    // Create our media library instance to get our photo.
    mediaLibrary = MLMediaLibrary(options: options)
    // We want to be called when media sources come in that's available (via observeValueForKeyPath).
    self.mediaLibrary.addObserver(self,
                                  forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey,
                                  options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
                                  context: &mediaSourcesContext)
    if (self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources != nil) {} // Reference returns nil but starts the asynchronous loading.
}

deinit {

    // Make sure to remove us as an observer before "mediaLibrary" is released.
    self.mediaLibrary.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey, context:&mediaSourcesContext)
}

// MARK: - NSCollectionViewDataSource

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
    print("photos.count \(photos.count)")
    return photos.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

    let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "IconItem", for:indexPath)
    let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
    let iconInfo = photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
    item.representedObject = iconInfo
    return item
}

// MARK: - NSCollectionViewDelegate

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {

    if let itemIndexPath = indexPaths.first {
        let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
        let itemDict = photos[((itemIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)] as! NSDictionary
        if let itemTitle = itemDict[ItemKeys.nameKey] as? String {
            if (itemTitle.characters.count > 0) {
                print("selected photo: '\(itemTitle)'")
            }
            else {
                print("selected photo: <no title>")
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Utilities

/// Helps to make sure the media object is the photo format we want.
private func isValidImage(_ mediaObject: MLMediaObject) -> Bool {

    var isValidImage = false

    let attrs = mediaObject.attributes
    let contentTypeStr = attrs[MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.contentTypeKey] as! String

    // We only want photos, not movies or older PICT formats (PICT image files are not supported in a sandboxed environment).
    if ((contentTypeStr != kUTTypePICT as String) && (contentTypeStr != kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie as String))
    {
        isValidImage = true
    }
    print("isValidImage: \(isValidImage)")
    //return isValidImage
    return true
}

/// Obtains the title of the MLMediaObject (either the meta name or the last component of the URL).
func imageTitle(_ fromMediaObject: MLMediaObject) -> String {

    guard let title = fromMediaObject.attributes["name"] else {
        return fromMediaObject.url!.lastPathComponent
    }
    return title as! String
}


// MARK: - Photo Loading

/// Observer for all key paths returned from the MLMediaLibrary.
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey && context == &mediaSourcesContext && object! is MLMediaLibrary) {

        // The media sources have loaded, we can access the its root media.

        if let mediaSource = self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources?[MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier] {
            self.mediaSource = mediaSource
        }
        else if let mediaSource = self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources?[MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier] {
            self.mediaSource = mediaSource
        }
        else {
            // Can't find any media sources.
            self.noPhotosLabel.isHidden = false

            // Stop progress indicator.
            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimation(self)

            return  // No photos found.
        }

        // Media Library is loaded now, we can access mediaSource for photos
        self.mediaSource.addObserver(self,
                                     forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey,
                                     options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
                                     context: &rootMediaGroupContext)

        // Obtain the media grouping (reference returns nil but starts asynchronous loading).
        if (self.mediaSource.rootMediaGroup != nil) {}
    }
    else if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey && context == &rootMediaGroupContext && object! is MLMediaSource) {

        // The root media group is loaded, we can access the media objects.

        // Done observing for media groups.
        self.mediaSource.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey, context:&rootMediaGroupContext)

        self.rootMediaGroup = self.mediaSource.rootMediaGroup
        self.rootMediaGroup.addObserver(self,
                                        forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey,
                                        options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
                                        context: &mediaObjectsContext)

        // Obtain the all the photos, (reference returns nil but starts asynchronous loading).
        if (self.rootMediaGroup.mediaObjects != nil) {}
    }
    else if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey && context == &mediaObjectsContext && object! is MLMediaGroup) {

        // The media objects are loaded, we can now finally access each photo.

        // Done observing for media objects that group.
        self.rootMediaGroup.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey, context:&mediaObjectsContext)

        // Stop progress indicator since we know if we have photos (or not).
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimation(self)

        let mediaObjects = self.rootMediaGroup.mediaObjects
        if (mediaObjects != nil && mediaObjects!.count > 0) {
            // Add photos to the array, to be used in our NSCollectionView.
            for mediaObject in mediaObjects! {
                if (self.isValidImage(mediaObject)) {    // Make sure the media object is a photo.

                    let title = self.imageTitle(mediaObject)

                    if let image = NSImage.init(contentsOf: mediaObject.thumbnailURL!) {
                        let iconItem : Dictionary = [ItemKeys.imageKey: image, ItemKeys.nameKey: title] as [String : Any]
                        self.arrayController.addObject(iconItem)
                    }
                }
            }

            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
        else {
            // No photos available.
            self.noPhotosLabel.isHidden = false
        }

        self.rootMediaGroup = nil // We are done with this.
    }
    else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

}
```

Can someone please throw some light here. I am a newbie and there is not enough documentation for Mac, though can find a lot on IOS.

Comment: Getting same error, different usage. Mine comes when I scroll my collection view, assuming it has to do with loading the image. This only started happening when I restored into a new machine this weekend. Wasn't happening on Friday, just started. :/

Answer (score 1):

The function `isValidImage()` is filtering out videos.